# Warning for unsaved changes inside a tab which is inside another tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

This is my code:

```
var tableSTART=$(".tbody").html();
$( ".selector" ).tabs({activate: function(event, ui) {
  var current=$(".tbody").html();
  if (current!= tableSTART) {
       BootstrapDialog.confirm({
            title: 'WARNING',
            message: 'You have not saved the changes.Do you want to save it?.',
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
            draggable: true,
            callback: function(result) {
                if(result) {
                    //var index = $('.selector a[href="'+"#"+tableCRAWLTYPE+'"]').parent().index();
                    var index = $('#tabs a[href="#your-tab"]').parent().index();
                    $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", index );
                    var tab = $( ".innerTab ul>li a:contains("+extractType+")" );
                      if(tab[0]) {
                        var tabid = tab[0].id;
                        var tabIndex = tabid.substr(tabid.length - 1);
                        $('.innerTab').tabs('option', 'active' , tabIndex-1);
                      }
                    //}
                    tableSTART=current;
                }
            }
        }); 
   //end dialog
        }
        else
        {   
            alert("not changed");

        }
    }
});
```

What I want is, When i make some change in table inside tab which is inside another tab, and try to move to other tab without saving then a warning message comes up saying "do you want to save". If user clicks "ok" it should stay on the same page, if "no", then it should be allowed to switch to other tab.

When i run the above when i make some change in the inner tab of some other tab then, warning message comes up and if i click "yes", again that popup comes up(i think because when i am making active tab as that what i clicked, `.tabs()` is called again )

How to correctly do it and How can i do this in a better way?

PS: I am comparing the `.tbody` html content before and after change. `tableSTART` is the intial content when the page loads and then i am adding some divs(textfields etc inside those div) dynamically.
and `current` checks for the current html inside innertab's `.tbody`

Comment: When you switch tabs, doesn't the original tab keep what the user entered? Why ask the user if they want to keep what they entered, when the browser is going to retain it anyway.

Comment: @Chad Hedgcock..actually in my page, first i am selecting a value from dropdown and based on that value i am displaying data inside the innertab..so its basically on same page.And this everything is dynamic(javascript and jquery) How is the browser going to retain this,I didn't get you. I basically want to get a warning message if i am moving to other tab from the current tab without saving the the current's tab's changes.

Comment: If the user enters data into one tab and then goes to the next tab, then they go back to tab 1, is their data gone?

Comment: no its not gone. Its there only